# What weights of the components of concrete do I need for my project?

Tags: concrete, materials

We need to mix 0.73 cubic metres of concrete for our shed slab.

We plan to mix C30 concrete as follows:

- 1 part cement
- 2 parts sand
- 3 parts coarse aggregate

I have tried to work out the quantity (in kg) of each material I should order 3 times, and am ashamed to say I have 3 different answers!

If anyone is willing to help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you calculating by weight or by volume?

Comment: The same calculator and the same numbers should give the same answer.  Are you changing anything when calculating?  What are you changing?  Have you thought about using the pre-mix bags or do you have a concrete place near by with small mix trailers?

Comment: @mrblint, `kg` are specified. That's a unit of mass (weight, in this case).

Comment: Sounds like you're in Europe...can you not buy bags of ready-mix concrete there?  Over across the pond here we have bags you can just add water and go—no sand/aggregate/portland cement mixing needed.

Comment: @Huesmann, for ~50 bags total it's probably cheaper to buy the components. Premix is usually marked up a fair bit due to the convenience factor and smaller volumes. It would definitely save mix work, though. That stuff is _heavy_.

Comment: @isherwood another suggestion might be for the OP to see if any concrete companies are willing to throw on an extra yard or more on a truck for a nearby job.  When the truck is done at the other job, it can come over and dump the rest of the load at the OP's shed.

Comment: If you calculate that you need 0.73 cubic meters, I think you need to prepare to make up 0.8 cubic meters or so to account for "stuff"...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need weight. Even though mixing by weight is a bit more accurate, the relative weights of the materials are close enough that volume is fine for a project that's not supercritical. Any seller should be able to sell by volume. But...

```
.73 m^3 / 6 = .122 m^3 to a part

.122m^3 x 1506kg/m^3 x 1 = 183.7kg of cement (~8 25kg bags)
.122m^3 x 1682kg/m^3 x 2 = 410.4kg of sand (~17 25kg bags)
.122m^3 x 1500kg/m^3 x 3 = 549.0kg of aggregate (~22 25kg bags)
```

All weights given by Google's AI results. Verify if you like.